# How to disable USB port?

Tags: usb, windows-registry

I know how to change registry key value name's data and if you want to disable USB port then change `Start` value name's data to 4 in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR
```

But as soon I change its values it prints *operation successfully* and after that operation, it overwrites this value to `3` automatically.

How to fix this?

Comment: Most reliable and secure way to disable USB port is to cut wires to on-board USB connector. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value of `Start` to 4 in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR`
will only work if the USB storage driver is already installed.
If it has not yet been installed, Windows plug & play subsystem automatically
resets the `Start` value to `3` (Manual) when it installs USBSTOR when a
USB storage device is plugged in for the first time.

A stronger method is given in the Microsoft article
[How can I prevent users from connecting to a USB storage device?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/823732/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-connecting-to-a-usb-storage-device)

This method assigns the user or the group and the local `SYSTEM` account `Deny`
permissions to the following files:

- `%SystemRoot%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf`
- `%SystemRoot%\Inf\Usbstor.inf`

See the article for details for doing that.

Another simpler method uses the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`):
Go to *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
Removable Storage Access* and set the required policy:

[image]